# Should I store my site's images on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Should I store my site's images on heroku?

images such as the logo of my site and so on.
I talking just about the images of the design of the site.

Will it affect my sites performance?

Comment: Heroku generally recommends keeping your slug size as small as possible, and I do believe the 'general' recommendation is to store such assets on a separate service such as Amazon S3. If your images are tiny and traffic is not astronomical, I imagine an exception wouldn't be the worst thing in the world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**. Your logo and other associated images that make up the site should not be terribly large, and will not negatively affect your slug size or slight performance much.

The downside of having these assets stored and served separately is that you application will not be all-together, which adds an extra layer of difficulty to development, as you have to update images in a separate place from your code.

Any large files uploaded by users, that are not part of the application itself but stored by it, should be stored on something like S3 (not that you can write to the Heroku FS anyway).

Answer (score 1):

typically anything that is core to my application (ie images for layout, logos etc) I commit to git and will deploy to Heroku - assets like uploaded images/pdfs etc all go to Heroku